# IntelliJ IDEA пропал плагин Database

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Раньше на панели рядом с мавеном была вкладка для работы с БД, но сейчас она пропала.
Где можно найти это средство Database sourse ?

Comment: @pavlofff, понял....спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `Community edition` такого нет. Либо покупать `Ultimate edition` ( есть триалка на 30 дней), либо не пользоваться этим сервисом.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Установите из репозитория нужный плагин]

Через настройки найдите плагин, который нужен для работы с БД

Answer (score 1):

Вот этот плагин: Database Tools and SQL обычно по умолчанию устанавливается, но если его нет нужно его выбрать в плагинах, тогда появится вкладка

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да все верно !! Его просто нет !! Может его как плагин установить ?

Comment: Проверьте установлен ли плагин Database Tools and Sql

Comment: нет в установленных, но и в поиску с таким названием ничего нет !!

Comment: переустановку IDE пробовали?

Comment: Через обзор плагины установите.

Comment: @s4urp8n, только что перестановил - результата нет !

Comment: А идея какая? Community edition или Ultimate edition?

Comment: @titov_andrei, "через обзор" - это как ?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov,  Community